# Is using Proguard with Android worth the effort?

Tags: android, proguard

I am about to finish my first Android application and I am trying to work out how to protect it with ProGuard.  My apps minimum API is 7 (Android 2.1).  I believe using Proguard would be easy if I set my minimum API to 9 (Android 2.3) but as a [lot of devices use 2.1 and 2.2](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)  I don't want to exclude them.

Everything I have read about using Proguard with Android seems confusing and difficult (I dont know anything about Ant scripts)  Does anyone know of a step-by-step guide for using Proguard for Android with Eclipse?

Is Proguard even worth bothering with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProGuard has nothing to do with the API level of your app. Newer versions of the Eclipse ADT have it integrated, so using it is just a matter of [adding a single line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html#enabling) to a configuration file, you don't need to use Ant. You might get some problems if ProGurad removes methods/classes you are actually using, and you will have to work around those by tweaking the ProGurad config file.

If you find it difficult to use, you can always launch your app without obfuscating it, and add ProGuard in a later version. If it is your first app, the chances of someone decompiling it to steal your super-secret code are pretty low :)

Comment: Oh, I see, thankyou. My project file doesn't have the proguard.cfg file maybe because I created the original project when version 2.1 was brand spanking new. I updated Eclipse a little while ago (a few weeks ago) but the proguard.cfg file did not automatically get added. A few seconds ago I made a new Android project with target 2.1 and the proguard.cfg file was there! I wonder if I can just copy and paste the proguard.cfg file to my original project, or, second preference, copy and paste my existing project into the new project file I made a couple of seconds ago...

Comment: proguard.cfg only gets generated for new projects, that's why you didn't have it. You can copy it to your 'old' project though, it's not project-dependent. After you configure its path in default.properties, ProGuard should be run on your classes when you export a release version from Eclipse.

Comment: Thankyou, I have the proguard.cfg file in my project and will follow ProGuard instructions at the Android developers site.  Much less daunting than having to use Ant scripts :-) http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html